# disabled my message on input if the user enter in the input disabledMessages

Tags: angular, validation, input

i want to add disable message option in my input

i explain you I have some rule with associated message and I want if the user tap disableMessage in her input

the message dont display I think in need to use the boolean condition but I dont know how

My code :

```
   @Input () ValidationHints: any

    ngOnInit() {
    this.required = this.required !== undefined && this.required !== false
    this.disabled = this.disabled !== undefined && this.disabled !== false
    this.readonly = this.readonly !== undefined && this.readonly !== false
    this.ngModelRef = ''

    this.ValidationHints = {

      required: 'This field is required.',
      minlength: 'Field must be at least ' + this.minlength + ' characters long.',
      maxlength: 'Field cannot be more than ' + this.maxlength + ' characters long.',
      pattern: 'Please match the requested format.'

    }
  }
```

and html input :

```
  <mae-input type="text"
           minlength="3"
           maxlength="10"
           pattern="[a-z]+"
           [withCharCount]="true"
           [(ngModel)]="input"
           required
>
</mae-input>
```

thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  the directive *ngIf="enableMessage" or [disabled]="disabled"

Comment: that disable my input and not my validation message

Comment: i want to disable juste my message and note all of my message if I use juste disableMessage all my message is disable but if he precise disableMessage.required is just the message about required who is disable